# Understanding DTO and Anemic Domain Model

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, n-tier-architecture

I am new to Domain Pattern, I need to ensure that I understand what I had read so far!!,  **Please tell me whether the following sentences are true or did not violate a principle related to DDD**

[image]

0) DAL will receive parameters in DTO and return fetched data in LIST of DTO (Entity)

1) De-couple BLL and DAL through repository pattern.

2) Entity is DTO object.

3) ProductCategoryData contains a list of ProductData.

4) It will be Anemic Domain Model ANTI Pattern if BLL.ProductCategory does not contain properties that describe the business object.

5) BLL.ProductCategory contains a List of BLL.Product……I have bad feeling about this

6) I avoid in that design anemic domain model anti pattern.

7) I successfully Apply Domain Model Pattern.

8) I used DTO objects to transfer data between tiers.

Please talk to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the interface and there are no methods on your objects then that is still an anemic model.

The Repository should be associate to the aggregates of the model. 
I your model only contains those entities then does not really matter how bad or good the design is
because the overall complexity will be low.

Also choose better names for your model, and avoid generic names like "Data". 
The reader immediately asks: what kind of data ?

Comment: "If that is the interface and there are no methods on your objects then that is still an anemic model."

But I used ListProductCategory in BLL.ProductCategory ??

Comment: that is an accessor not a behaviour

Comment: So If I add Susbscribe method, it will be not anemic.

But what if some of the objects in the system, does not have a behavior by its natural.  I am confused?

Comment: Entities will always have at least some behaviour. If they really don't have any behaviour then they are Value Objects.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have a bad feeling?  Anemic sounds like a bad word, but what harm have you detected?

I see objects that don't have any behavior as anemic.  I don't judge by data members.

If you choose for other reasons to move that behavior somewhere else (e.g. services), there's an argument that you're choosing an architecture that's more functional than object-oriented.  Is that really so bad?

I think labels like anemic can sound bad, but they really just describe one person's design decision.  It might also reveal someone's OOP bias.  A functional language would be considered anemic by an OOP practitioner, but it's not necessarily fatal.

A better question to ask is: "Do I have parallel models?  One for DTO and another for business layer?"  If yes, I'd say that dual maintenance is far more harmful than anemia.

Comment: I saw a system, that has a DTOs passed around 
UI<->BLL static classes <-> DAL

Now consider a DTO.Student which has a DTO.Class, then at certain point, the requirement changed and the Student can attend several classes.

Then I will have code to change in all tiers, in order to convert Student.Class to Student.Classes., or even worse by putting Students in Class.